# Running django with ASGI?

Tags: django, gunicorn, uvicorn, asgi

- I have a django app
- I using this [docker] (https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-docker) for production deployment

when I run the app using:

```
gunicorn --log-level debug --workers 3 myapp.asgi:application --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

I see the warning

```
ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
```

1. after reading [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31508) I understand that django do not support, but is this have any effect on my app? or where should the effect be?
2. My app is using sync endpoints, for example:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = My.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

is by  running using ASGI the call to the database would be async?

- I don't use any web sockets

3. I can see online many version for the asgi.py file, with manny different middleware and the `django.setup()` keyword, where can I find a documentation about the use cases?

Comment: Better one question at one post... Lifespan is just a event so, like if the application start up, it will know, restart, then it will know only.

Answer (score 0):

1. I doesn't seem that the `lifespan` feature should be blocking any Django apps that are not using that feature.
2. If you use sync code in your views, then switching to ASGI doesn't magically make your view asynchronously. You need async wrappers around it. Check out [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/) about the adapters `sync_to_async()` and `async_to_sync()`.
3. I have never seen the usage of `django.setup()`. I don't understand your question fully. This is how an `asgi.py` file should look like:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyService.settings.local')
application = get_asgi_application()
```

Still, personally, after setting this all up, my views are still synchronously. I have opened this question about it: [Uvicorn async workers are still working synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864474/uvicorn-async-workers-are-still-working-synchronously)

Answer (score -1):

```
exec envdir .envdir gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --timeout 300 \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --preload \
  -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Comment: How does it answer the questions? Can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.