# Uvicorn async workers are still working synchronously

Tags: python, django, uvicorn, daphne, asgi

**Question in short**

I have migrated my project from Django 2.2 to Django 3.2, and now I want to start using the possibility for asynchronous views. I have created an async view, setup asgi configuration, and run gunicorn with a Uvicorn worker. When swarming this server with 10 users concurrently, they are served synchronously. What do I need to configure in order to serve 10 concurrent users an async view?

**Question in detail**

This is what I did so far in my local environment:

- I am working with Django 3.2.10 and Python 3.9.
- I have installed `gunicorn` and `uvicorn` through pip
- I have created an `asgi.py` file with the following contents

```
    import os
    from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyService.settings.local')
    application = get_asgi_application()
```

- I have created a view with the following implementation, and connected it in `urlpatterns`:

```
    import asyncio
    import json
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    
    async def async_sleep(request):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'mode': 'async', 'time': 1).encode())
```

- I run locally a gunicorn server with a Uvicorn worker:

```
gunicorn MyService.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2022-01-26 14:37:14 +0100] [8732] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-01-26 14:37:14 +0100] [8732] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8732)
[2022-01-26 14:37:14 +0100] [8732] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2022-01-26 14:37:14 +0100] [8733] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8733
[2022-01-26 13:37:15 +0000] [8733] [INFO] Started server process [8733]
[2022-01-26 13:37:15 +0000] [8733] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-01-26 13:37:15 +0000] [8733] [INFO] ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
[2022-01-26 13:37:15 +0000] [8733] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

- I hit the API from a local client once. After 1 second, I get a 200 OK, as expected.
- I set up a locust server to spawn concurrent users. When I let it make requests with 1 concurrent user, every 1 second an API call is completed.
- When I let it make requests with 10 concurrent users, every 1 second an API call is completed. All other requests are waiting.

This last thing is not what I expect. I expect the worker, while sleeping asynchronously, to pick up the next request already. Am I missing some configuration?

I also tried it by using Daphne instead of Uvicorn, but with the same result.

**Locust**

This is how I have set up my locust.

- Start a new virtualenv
- `pip install locust`
- Create a `locustfile.py` with the following content:

```
from locust import HttpUser, task
class SleepUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def async_sleep(self):
        self.client.get('/api/async_sleep/')
```

- Run the locust executable from the shell
- Visit http://0.0.0.0:8089 in the browser
- Set number of workers to 10, spawn rate to 1 and host to http://127.0.0.1:8000

**Middleware**

These are my middleware settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusBeforeMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'shared.common.middleware.ApiLoggerMiddleware',
    'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusAfterMiddleware',
]
```

The ApiLoggerMiddleware from shared is from our own code, I will investigate this one first. This is the implementation of it.

```
import logging
import os
from typing import List

from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.utils import timezone

from shared.common.authentication_service import BaseAuthenticationService


class ApiLoggerMiddleware:
    TOO_BIG_FOR_LOG_BYTES = 2 * 1024

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        # The get_response callable is provided by Django, it is a function
        # that takes a request and returns a response. Plainly put, once we're
        # done with the incoming request, we need to pass it along to get the
        # response which we need to ultimately return.
        self._get_response = get_response
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('api')
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        self.request_time = None
        self.response_time = None

    def __call__(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
        common_data = self.on_request(request)
        response = self._get_response(request)
        self.on_response(response, common_data)
        return response

    def truncate_body(self, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        return f"{request.body[:self.TOO_BIG_FOR_LOG_BYTES]}"

    def on_request(self, request: HttpRequest) -> List[str]:
        self.request_time = timezone.now()

        remote_address = self.get_remote_address(request)
        user_agent = request.headers.get('User-Agent') or ''
        customer_uuid = self.get_customer_from_request_auth(request)
        method = request.method
        uri = request.get_raw_uri()

        common = [
            remote_address,
            user_agent,
            customer_uuid,
            method,
            uri
        ]

        in_line = [
                      "IN",
                      str(self.pid),
                      str(self.request_time),
                  ] + common + [
                      self.truncate_body(request)
                  ]

        self.logger.info(', '.join(in_line))
        return common

    def on_response(self, response: HttpResponse, common: List[str]) -> None:
        self.response_time = timezone.now()

        out_line = [
                       "OUT",
                       str(self.pid),
                       str(self.response_time)
                   ] + common + [
                       str(self.response_time - self.request_time),
                       str(response.status_code),
                   ]
        self.logger.info(", ".join(out_line))

    @classmethod
    def get_customer_from_request_auth(cls, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if not token:
            return 'no token'
        try:
            payload = BaseAuthenticationService.validate_access_token(token)
            return payload.get('amsOrganizationId', '')
        except Exception:
            return 'unknown'

    @classmethod
    def get_remote_address(cls, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        if 'X-Forwarded-For' in request.headers:
            # in case the request comes in through a proxy, the remote address
            # will be just the last proxy that passed it along, that's why we
            # have to get the remote from X-Forwarded-For
            # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For
            addresses = request.headers['X-Forwarded-For'].split(',')
            client = addresses[0]
            return client
        else:
            return request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '')
```

**Sources**

Sources I have used:

- [A Guide to ASGI in Django 3.0 and its performance](https://arunrocks.com/a-guide-to-asgi-in-django-30-and-its-performance/)
- [How to use Django with Uvicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/uvicorn/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ApiLoggerMiddleware` is a synchronous middleware.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#async-views, **emphasis** mine:

> You will only get the benefits of a fully-asynchronous request stack if you have no synchronous middleware loaded into your site. **If there is a piece of synchronous middleware, then Django must use a thread per request to safely emulate a synchronous environment for it.**
>
> Middleware can be built to support both sync and async contexts. Some of Django’s middleware is built like this, but not all. **To see what middleware Django has to adapt, you can turn on debug logging for the `django.request` logger and look for log messages about “Synchronous middleware … adapted”.**

(The log message currently says "Asynchronous middleware ... adapted", bug reported at [#33495](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33495).)

Turn on debug logging for the `django.request` logger  by adding this to your `LOGGING` setting:

```py
'django.request': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
},
```

## Solution

To make `ApiLoggerMiddleware` asynchronous:

1. Inherit `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin`.

   - call `super().__init__(get_response)` in `__init__`.
   - remove `__call__`; `MiddlewareMixin.__call__` makes your middleware asynchronous.
2. Refactor `on_request` to `process_request`.

   - return `None` instead of `common`.
   - attach `common` to `request` instead: `request.common = common`.
     remember to update references to `request.common`.
   - attach `request_time` to `request` instead of `self` to make it (and the middleware) thread-safe.
     remember to update references to `request.request_time`.
3. Refactor `on_response(self, response, common)` to `process_response(self, request, response)`.

   - return `response`.
   - don't attach `response_time` to `self`; leave it as a variable since it's not used in other functions.

The result:

```py
class ApiLoggerMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    TOO_BIG_FOR_LOG_BYTES = 2 * 1024

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        # The get_response callable is provided by Django, it is a function
        # that takes a request and returns a response. Plainly put, once we're
        # done with the incoming request, we need to pass it along to get the
        # response which we need to ultimately return.
        super().__init__(get_response)  # +
        self._get_response = get_response
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('api')
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        # self.request_time = None   # -
        # self.response_time = None  # -

    # def __call__(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:  # -
    #     common_data = self.on_request(request)                 # -
    #     response = self._get_response(request)                 # -
    #     self.on_response(response, common_data)                # -
    #     return response                                        # -

    def truncate_body(self, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        return f"{request.body[:self.TOO_BIG_FOR_LOG_BYTES]}"

    # def on_request(self, request: HttpRequest) -> List[str]:  # -
    def process_request(self, request: HttpRequest) -> None:    # +
        # self.request_time = timezone.now()   # -
        request.request_time = timezone.now()  # +

        remote_address = self.get_remote_address(request)
        user_agent = request.headers.get('User-Agent') or ''
        customer_uuid = self.get_customer_from_request_auth(request)
        method = request.method
        uri = request.get_raw_uri()

        common = [
            remote_address,
            user_agent,
            customer_uuid,
            method,
            uri
        ]

        in_line = [
            "IN",
            str(self.pid),
            # str(self.request_time),   # -
            str(request.request_time),  # +
        ] + common + [
            self.truncate_body(request)
        ]

        self.logger.info(', '.join(in_line))
        # return common          # -
        request.common = common  # +
        return None              # +

    # def on_response(self, response: HttpResponse, common: List[str]) -> None:                # -
    def process_response(self, request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse) -> HttpResponse:  # +
        # self.response_time = timezone.now()  # -
        response_time = timezone.now()         # +

        out_line = [
            "OUT",
            str(self.pid),
            # str(self.response_time)  # -
            str(response_time)         # +
            # ] + common + [                    # -
        ] + getattr(request, 'common', []) + [  # +
            # str(self.response_time - self.request_time),             # -
            str(response_time - getattr(request, 'request_time', 0)),  # +
            str(response.status_code),
        ]
        self.logger.info(", ".join(out_line))
        return response  # +

    @classmethod
    def get_customer_from_request_auth(cls, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if not token:
            return 'no token'
        try:
            payload = BaseAuthenticationService.validate_access_token(token)
            return payload.get('amsOrganizationId', '')
        except Exception:
            return 'unknown'

    @classmethod
    def get_remote_address(cls, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
        if 'X-Forwarded-For' in request.headers:
            # in case the request comes in through a proxy, the remote address
            # will be just the last proxy that passed it along, that's why we
            # have to get the remote from X-Forwarded-For
            # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For
            addresses = request.headers['X-Forwarded-For'].split(',')
            client = addresses[0]
            return client
        else:
            return request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '')
```